# Onclick on graphView, Get value for current plot

Tags: android

In my project graph in required, and I am getting correct horizontal and vertical values in graph. But the problem is the graph contains huge data. That's why I made it scrollable. But I want on click on graph view It should show the plot value.

```
graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setGridColor(color.black);
    graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setHorizontalLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setVerticalLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setTextSize(10);
    graphView.setScalable(true);
    graphView.setScrollable(true);
    graphView.setViewPort(2, 40);
```

I am using this link for creating graph.
[graph view library](http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html)

Comment: Switch to achartengine. Achartengine is capable of doing just about anything that can be done with charts.

Comment: Thanks Umesh, but I didn't find any link to download achartEngine complete library, can you please suggest me the link.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...
here are the related links - 
http://www.achartengine.org/
http://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/